# Nginx k8s cluster ingress

Tags: nginx, kubernetes, digital-ocean, kubernetes-helm

I have 2 kubernetes clusters on digitalocean. One cluster has nginx installed via helm:

```
helm install nginx bitnami/nginx
```

I need to "whitelist" the other cluster IP address. So basically one cluster can receive incoming calls to an endpoint from a specific cluster.

I don't know how to configure the helm values.yaml file generated. Normally with nginx we can use:

```
whitelist-source-range
```

But the helm chart i don't know how to do it.
thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whitelist-source-range is an [annotation](https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx/user-guide/nginx-configuration/annotations/#whitelist-source-range) that can be added to an Ingress object, for example:

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: whitelist
  annotations:
    ingress.kubernetes.io/whitelist-source-range: "1.1.1.1/24"
spec:
  rules:
  - host: whitelist.test.net
  http:
    paths:
    - path: /
    backend:
      serviceName: webserver
      servicePort: 80
```

You may also need to change `service.externalTrafficPolicy` to `Local`